# Flutter mapbox_search : Is any way to get city name of a address?

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter mapbox_search :
Is any way to get city name of a address ?

as of now we can get only,

```
String id; 
FeatureType type; 
List<PlaceType> placeType; 
String addressNumber; 
Properties properties; 
String text; 
String placeName; 
List<double> bbox; 
List<double> center; 
Geometry geometry; 
List<Context> context; 
String matchingText; 
String matchingPlaceName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got temporary solution,
The mapbox always give address in pattern ,

example : Washington Heights, New York, New York 10033, United States.

So that,

```
var name = place.placeName;
var cityname;

List names = name.replaceAll(' ','').split(',');

if (names.length > 3) {
  cityname = names[names.length - 3];
} else {
  cityname = names[0];
}
```

comment down if you get any easy way